# Looping within spreadsheet pairs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, spreadsheet

I have 10 different spreadsheets(a,b,c,d,e,f etc.) in a single excel document. How I can create a loop in order to compare specific pairs of spreadsheets (a vs d, b vs e, c vs f, etc)?

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim year1, year2 As Integer
Dim strname1, strname2, strname3, strname4 As String
Dim st
Dim p
strname1 = "Female"
strname2 = "Male"
strname3 = "Other"
strname4 = "Unknown"
year1 = 2019
year2 = 2020
For Each p In Array(2019, 2020)
For Each st In Array(strname1, strname2, strname3, strname4)
    Worksheets("a").Activate
    x = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("F9:F250"), Range("C9:C250"), p, Range("E9:E250"), st)
    Worksheets("d").Activate
    y = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("F7:F30"), Range("C7:C30"), p, Range("D7:D30"), st)
 If x = y Then
  MsgBox "Number of people correctly validated for" & " " & p & " " & st
Else
  MsgBox "Error in validation for" & " " & p & " " & st
End If

Next st
Next p
```

Comment: What do you mean "Specific pairs of spreadsheets". Do you have these pairs you wish to compare defined somewhere (perhaps a 2-dim array or even another sheet)? Wherever you have those pairs stored (besides your brain) is what you want to loop over. Like.. `For Each pairRow in Sheets("myPairs").Range("A1:B10").Rows` (as an example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have these pairs defined. For example, I want to compare a vs d, b vs e,  c vs f, and h vs g. From a,b,c, and h spreadsheets  I have to select the exact same ranges of cells, and from the  d,e,f and g the exact same ranges of cells.

Comment: Your use of the word "spreadsheets" is confusing. It sounds like you mean WORKSHEETS instead.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I mean WORKSHEETS

Answer (score 0):

In a new sheet in the same workbook (lets name it `myPairs`) in columns A and B enter your pairs like:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| a | e |
| b | f |
| c | g |
| d | h |
+---+---+
```

Now you can introduce a loop into your code:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim year1, year2 As Integer
Dim strname1, strname2, strname3, strname4 As String
Dim st
Dim p
strname1 = "Female"
strname2 = "Male"
strname3 = "Other"
strname4 = "Unknown"
year1 = 2019
year2 = 2020
For each pairRow in Sheets("myPairs").Range("A1:B4").Rows
  firstSheetName = pairRow.Cells(1,1)
  secondSheetName = pairRow.Cells(1,2)
  For Each p In Array(2019, 2020)
    For Each st In Array(strname1, strname2, strname3, strname4)
      Worksheets(firstSheetName).Activate
      x = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("F9:F250"), Range("C9:C250"), p, Range("E9:E250"), st)
      Worksheets(secondSheetName).Activate
      y = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("F7:F30"), Range("C7:C30"), p, Range("D7:D30"), st)
      If x = y Then
        MsgBox "Number of people correctly validated for" & " " & p & " " & st
      Else
        MsgBox "Error in validation for" & " " & p & " " & st
      End If

    Next st
  Next p
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.It's fine now